# How Do You Compensate For Scroll Bar In Browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

Is there way to dynamically compensate for when the scroll bar appears and it shifts the wrapper over from center?

Answer (score 4):

What I tend to do with layouts that are very sensitive to the scroll bar disappearing (like centered elements) is enforce a scroll bar on every page:

```
body { overflow-y: scroll }
```

this is the one thing that I think Internet Explorer handles better by default: It always reserves space for the scoll bar, allowing for a much smoother experience when switching between pages on the same site.

Comment: Unfortunately, IE9 joined the bandwagon of "no unnecessary scrollbars". This bit of CSS is the best thing ever :D

Comment: Another option is to set a `min-height` on your wrapper

Comment: Forcing a scrollbar on all pages just sucks as an option.